# Loading a PowerShell hashtable from a file?

Tags: powershell

I've got a file containing some data in PowerShell Object Notation:

```
@{ X = 'x'; Y = 'y' }
```

I'd like to load this into a variable from the file.

Comment: For an array of hashes, would each line be enclosed in @{ }, such as @{Z = 'z'; A='a' }?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*(I figured it out while putting together a repro)*

```
PS> $content = ( Get-Content .\foo.pson | Out-String )
PS> $data = ( Invoke-Expression $content )
```

`Get-Content` returns an array with the lines in the file; the `Out-String` is used to join them together.

`Invoke-Expression` then runs the script, and the result is captured. This is open to injection attacks, but that's OK in my specific case.

Or, if you prefer your PowerShell terse:

```
PS> $data = gc .\foo.pson | Out-String | iex
```

(I can't find a shorter form of `Out-String`)

Comment: Maybe this is a Powershell 4 thing but I am able to skip the Out-String part and simply do:
    $hash = Get-Content .\file.pson | Invoke-Expression

Answer (score 12):

I've used ConvertFrom-StringData. If you want to use this approach you'll need to change the way you store key/value pairs with each on its own line and no quotes:

```
#Contents of test.txt
X = x
Y = y

get-content .\test.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData

Name                           Value
----                           -----
X                              x
Y                              y
```

ConvertFrom-StringData is a built-in cmdlet. I created corresponding ConvertTo-StringData function available here http://poshcode.org/1986

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question (to keep things simple), but the file actually contains an object tree: an array of hashtables, containing other arrays and hashtables.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into trouble using ConvertFrom-StringData as @Chad suggested. If you do:

```
$hash = get-content .\test.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

I found I had an object array rather than a hash table. In fact, it appears that I had an array of hash tables, each with one entry. I confirmed with a:

```
$hash.GetType()
```

It looks like you need to join each line of the slurped input file to ensure that it forms a single string for ConvertFrom..'s use:

```
$hash = ((get-content .\test.txt) -join '`n') | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Comment: You can also just use `Get-Content -Raw .\test.txt` which stops the file being piped line by line to `ConvertFrom-StringData`; http://www.geekality.net/2014/06/30/powershell-read-hashtable-from-a-file/

Answer (score 7):

Starting from PowerShell 5.0 you have

```
Import-PowerShellDataFile
```

Which imports values from a .psd1-file. So the only thing you have to do is rename your file to *.psd1

Official help is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile?view=powershell-5.0).

Comment: You actually don't even need to rename the file. Tested with .pson

Answer (score 5):

If you can give this file the extension `.ps1`, say, `data.ps1` then it cannot be simpler than this code:

```
$data = <path>\data.ps1
```

Comment: True (and I didn't realise that I didn't have to dot-source the file) , but then it looks like it can be run directly, which I don't particularly want.

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post but, this is sort of a twist on your accepted solution and perhaps slightly more "safe", keep in mind un-trusted files.

From your notes, you have a file that contains a hashtable using Powershell syntax.  Given that constraint, you can import it directly:

```
$HashPath = ".\foo.pson"
# input file contents
$filecontent = Get-Content -Path $HashPath -Raw -ErrorAction Stop
# put the file in a script block
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create( $filecontent )
#check that the file contains no other Powershell commands
$scriptBlock.CheckRestrictedLanguage( $allowedCommands, $allowedVariables, $true )
#execute it to create the hashtable 
$hashtable = ( & $scriptBlock )
```

Note on the `$scriptBlock.CheckRestrictedLanguage` you could replace that with

```
$scriptBlock.CheckRestrictedLanguage([string[]]@(), [string[]]@(), $false)
```

Use an empty list of strings so we do not allow any Powershell commands. When importing a hashtable, this is exactly what we want.  That last one is `allowEnvironmentVariables` so we restrict that in this example with `$false`.

Side note, a Powershell module (psd1 file) is just a hashtable so this concept may help you to also pull in script blocks or other things.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.checkrestrictedlanguage?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0