# Save hash table in PowerShell object notation (PSON)

Tags: powershell, serialization, expression, powershell-2.0

The question [Loading a PowerShell hashtable from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743892/loading-a-powershell-hashtable-from-a-file) documents how to load a file that contains a hashtable in PSON format into a variable, but how does one save a hashtable to a file in PSON format?

Hashtable:

```
@{            
 "name" = "report 0"            
 "parameters" = @(
    @{"name" = "parameter 0"; "default" = 1; "values"=1,2,3,4},
    @{"name" = "parameter 1"; "default" = 'A'; "values" = 'A','B','C'}
    )            
}
```

Comment: There is nothing like this built-in. Presumably you have to write your own solution but it's a tough task unless you are going to allow only limited subset of data types, no recursion in nested objects, etc.

Comment: Excellent question, but I'm curious as to where the term PSON came from; it seems that it never really caught on. More precisely, it is a _hashtable literal_ notation (which since v3 forms _part_ of the syntactic sugar for custom-object construction; e.g. `[pscustomobject] @{name="foo";age=21}`, but you cannot use that in data files loaded with `Import-PowerShellDataFile`, which only support hashtable literals)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `*-CliXml` cmdlets. To save the object:

```
@{            
 "name" = "report 0"            
 "parameters" = @(
    @{"name" = "parameter 0"; "default" = 1; "values"=1,2,3,4},
    @{"name" = "parameter 1"; "default" = 'A'; "values" = 'A','B','C'}
    )            
} | Export-Clixml -Path c:\hash.xml
```

To read it back:

```
Import-Clixml c:\hash.xml
```

Comment: I would prefer PSON, as it is easier to read and edit than the XML that is generated by Import-Clixml.

Comment: If it's a matter of "readability", V3 lets you convert to JSON, which might actually be better.

Comment: Yes, I did read that.  Unfortunately, my client is still on Windows XP, which doesn't support v2.

Comment: IIRC the clixml cmdlets introduced in v1 but I might be wrong

Comment: @craig This would be the proper, built-in way to do it, if there wasn't anybody like iRon to build a custom solution for you (which might very likely still have a lot of unknown issues.)

Answer (score 14):

After 5 years, the cmdlet I had pasted in the original answer has undergone so many updates that it has become completely outdated. Therefore I have replaced the [code](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertTo-Expression/blob/master/ConvertTo-Expression.ps1) and the [ReadMe](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertTo-Expression/blob/master/README.md) with a link to the latest version.

### ConvertTo-Expression

The [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet can be download from PowerShell Gallery using the command:

```
Install-Script -Name ConvertTo-Expression
```

### ReadMe

The full ReadMe (and source code) is available from the [GitHub](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertTo-Expression)

### Answer

Below are some possible options to serialize the specific example (assigned to `$Craig`) in the question:

```
ConvertTo-Expression $Craig
@{
    parameters =
        @{
            name = 'parameter 0'
            default = 1
            values =
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
        },
        @{
            name = 'parameter 1'
            default = 'A'
            values =
                'A',
                'B',
                'C'
        }
    name = 'report 0'
}
```

**To limit the tree view expansion:**
<sub>(`Expand -0` will output a single line and `Expand -1` will remove also the unnecessary spaces)</sub>

```
ConvertTo-Expression $Craig -expand 3
@{
    parameters =
        @{name = 'parameter 0'; default = 1; values = 1, 2, 3, 4},
        @{name = 'parameter 1'; default = 'A'; values = 'A', 'B', 'C'}
    name = 'report 0'
}
```

**Preserving the explicit types (strong typed):**

```
ConvertTo-Expression $Craig -expand 3 -Strong
[hashtable]@{
    parameters = [array](
        [hashtable]@{name = [string]'parameter 0'; default = [int]1; values = [array]([int]1, [int]2, [int]3, [int]4)},
        [hashtable]@{name = [string]'parameter 1'; default = [string]'A'; values = [array]([string]'A', [string]'B', [string]'C')}
    )
    name = [string]'report 0'
}
```

<sub>(Note: As per PowerShell design, HashTables are not in order, but if required you might use the `[Ordered]` type instead.)</sub>

Comment: Or got to an elevated powershell and `Install-Script ConvertTo-Expression -Scope AllUsers` which places the script into `$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts` (which might not exit if this is your first script). That adds `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts` (typical path) to your `$env:path` but only elevated. Back to standard ps and do `$env:Path = "$env:Path$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts;"` then just `. ConvertTo-Expression.ps1` in any prompt or script you want to use it. Call function as `ConvertTo-Expression ...`

Comment: [sorry editing time ran out]. Better in the elevated powershell, after `Install-Script` to do `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path',$env:path,'machine')` to add the `...\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts` dir to the path for the whole system, elevated and non elevated PS and everything else.

Comment: Also the ReadMe link is incorrect (and suggested edit queue is full). Easy to find: https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertTo-Expression#readme

Comment: @john v kumpf, I have changed the embedded function to cmdlet script which makes it easier installable.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to put the hashtable definition in a scriptblock:

```
$hashtable = {
  @{            
    "name" = "report 0"            
    "parameters" = @(
        @{"name" = "parameter 0"; "default" = 1; "values"=1,2,3,4},
        @{"name" = "parameter 1"; "default" = 'A'; "values" = 'A','B','C'}
        )            
    }
}

$hashtable.tostring()
```

@{
    "name" = "report 0"
    "parameters" = @(
        @{"name" = "parameter 0"; "default" = 1; "values"=1,2,3,4},
        @{"name" = "parameter 1"; "default" = 'A'; "values" = 'A','B','C'}
        )
    }

Within the script, you'd need to invoke the script block to instantiate the hashtable:

```
$hash = .$hashtable
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem like I'd be able to load changes to the hashtable from a file if it is embedded in a script block.

Answer (score 0):

How to use a shorthand "object notation" to generate an object in PowerShell:

```
$object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{name="foo";age=21}
```

DISCLAIMER: I know this does not answer OP's question directly but it might help folks like me searching for a very similar issue and landing here.

Comment: Since v3 there's syntactic sugar that is not only more concise, but also more efficient, in addition to preserving the property order: `[pscustomobject] @{name="foo";age=21}`