# Powershell ConvertTo-json with embedded hashtable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm having a problem with ConvertTo-Json and was trying to understand the behavior and/or what I'm doing wrong.

Consider this sequence of commands:

```
$val=@{ID=10;Config=@{ID=11;Config=@{ID=12;Config='end'}}}
ConvertTo-json $val
ConvertTo-json @($val)
```

The first conversion gives this output:

```
{
    "ID":  10,
    "Config":  {
                   "ID":  11,
                   "Config":  {
                                  "ID":  12,
                                  "Config":  "end"
                              }
               }
}
```

The second conversion gives this output:

```
[
    {
        "ID":  10,
        "Config":  {
                       "ID":  11,
                       "Config":  "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                   }
    }
]
```

It seems that in the array case the conversion is incorrect.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's a trouble with the depth,  the default value is 2, can you try :

```
ConvertTo-json @($val) -Depth 5
```

Comment: Nice, spent a good chunk of the day today trying to figure out why some JSON at depth 3 was coming out as `"@{name=1.0}"`. I even asked a question and everything, before finally coming across this partially on accident.

Comment: Is there any way to specify "infinite depth"?

Comment: I can't find any information about that in Microsoft documentation. I never test more than 6. An "infinite depth" is theorical, do you really need more than 32.

Comment: Thank you for this.  This bug is extremely embarrassing.  Jeez, Microsoft!

Comment: IMO, the default of 2 violates the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). The scripter wants the entire object graph to be serialized properly in most cases. Definitely a bad API design on this cmdlet.

Comment: Consider [PSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139552/save-hash-table-in-powershell-object-notation-pson)

Comment: I agree with Nathan. If they were really concerned with hugely deep trees, then they should have made "depth" paramter mandatory. That would be better than a default of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Depth $([int32]::MaxValue)
```

specifies infinite depth (maximum possible for ConvertTo-Json cmdlet)

Comment: ConvertTo-Json : The maximum depth allowed for serialization is 100.

Comment: Using larger values than needed produces totally stupid performance hits. dont even go there

Comment: @ConradB Just wondering... Do you know that for a fact? I assumed that would be the case as it explain why there is a Depth parameter, but have you run tests?

Comment: I was forced to use depth 15 on a hacked block of text I got out of the game Sunless Sea, it was terribly slow, unsure why, but in real life in workplace also found that using larger values than 20 on really long documents, of object depth ~10 took far longer, which is illogical since its' a pickle operation (maybe the document model/map is inefficient at large values).