# How to get the API token for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use the Jenkins [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API. In the instructions it says I need to have the API key. I have looked all over the configuration pages to find it. How do I get the API key for Jenkins?

Comment: If you want the same programmatically, then you can have a look at [Programmatically retrieve Jenkins REST API Token](https://medium.com/@samratshaw/programmatically-retrieve-jenkins-rest-api-token-f2c3f0d69483)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Since Jenkins 2.129 the API token configuration [has changed](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/new-api-token-system/):

You can now have multiple tokens and name them. They can be revoked individually.

1. Log in to Jenkins.
2. Click you name (upper-right corner).
3. Click **Configure** (left-side menu).
4. Use "Add new Token" button to generate a new one then name it.
5. You must copy the token when you generate it as you cannot view the token afterwards.
6. Revoke old tokens when no longer needed.

Before Jenkins 2.129: Show the API token as follows:

1. Log in to Jenkins.
2. Click your name (upper-right corner).
3. Click **Configure** (left-side menu).
4. Click **Show API Token**.

The API token is revealed.

You can change the token by clicking the **Change API Token** button.

Comment: is there any api to get that ?

Comment: will this token expired?

Comment: `Show API Token` is no longer valid it seems.

Comment: @MadhuAvinash See my answer below

Comment: FYI. On Jenkins 2.150.1 the "Add new Token" button doesn't seem to appear until at least one token exists. Please check @RaGe's answer for how to do it without the UI.

Comment: Permissions info - somewhat surprisingly, users can create their own API tokens even if they are granted read only access. Overall/Administer permission is required for cross user token creation.

Answer (score 25):

The non UI way to do this post Jenkins 2.129 is:

```
curl 'https://<jenkinsURL>/me/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' \
--data 'newTokenName=foo' \
--user username:Password
```

which returns:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "tokenName": "foo",
    "tokenUuid": "<uuid>",
    "tokenValue": "<redacted>"
  }
}
```

---

**Pre** Jenkins 2.129

```
curl http://<username>:<password>@<jenkins-url>/me/configure
```

Comment: You need to include the CSRF crumb (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) in your curl request, else it will fail with 403:Forbidden.

Comment: What if username is name@domain.com, we have enabled single sign on in jenkins server

Comment: @SibiCoder Try replacing '@' with '%40'

Comment: this is not work 2.346.2,it returns in html: HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Answer (score 12):

**Tested in Jenkins 2.225**

After making research for several hours I could find the answer:

The API token is used instead of the CSFR token. However, what happens if you want to make authentication from any other client ([Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), CLI, [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), etc.)?

First you need to get a CSFR token and save the information in a cookie with `--cookie-jar`

#### Request

> curl -s --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies -u username:password
> http://localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json

#### Response

> {
> "_class": "hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
> "crumb": "bc92944100d12780cfc251c9255f3f323a475562b4ee0d8b9cc6e4121f50a450",
> "crumbRequestField": "Jenkins-Crumb" }

Then we can read the cookie with `--cookie` and generate the new token:

#### Request

> curl -X POST -H
> 'Jenkins-Crumb:your_crumb_token_generated_above'
> --cookie /tmp/cookies http://localhost:8080/me/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken?newTokenName=\your_token_name
> -u username:password

#### Response

> {
> "status": "ok",
> "data": {
> "tokenName": "my android token",
> "tokenUuid": "c510e26c-b2e8-4021-bf79-81d1e4c112af",
> "tokenValue": "11a2a0c91913d1391d8e8cb155ca714581"
> } }

Comment: It was necessary for me to add `-H "Content-Length: 0"` to the cURL request, but otherwise this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

#### How to a generate Jenkins API token

The following commands need curl and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Execute them in the same session.

```
# Change the following appropriately
JENKINS_URL="http://localhost:8080"
JENKINS_USER=admin
JENKINS_USER_PASS=admin
```

**Get the Crumb**

```bash
JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS" -s --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
```

**Get the access token**

```bash
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -u "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS" -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -s \
                    --cookie /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/me/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' \
                    --data 'newTokenName=GlobalToken' | jq -r '.data.tokenValue')
```

**Consecutive API calls**

Instead of the password, you need to use the token with the username along with the crumb that was generated.

```bash
curl -u $JENKINS_USER:$ACCESS_TOKEN \
     -H $JENKINS_CRUMB \ ..........
```

Comment: You don't need a CRUMB anymore, if you authenticate via the api-token, do you?

Comment: @Kutzi although docmentation says otherwise, I couldn't get the API calls to work without the CRUMB. If you succeed, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

This script works for me to generate API token, on `Jenkins` version `2.426.3` using `Ansible`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/var/lib/jenkins/api_token.txt

if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$FILE exists."
else 
    echo "$FILE does not exist."
    JENKINS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    JENKINS_USER=admin
    JENKINS_USER_PASS={{ jenkins_admin_password }}

    JENKINS_CRUMB=$(curl -u $JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS -s -c /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/crumbIssuer/api/json' | jq -r '.crumb')
    ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -u $JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_USER_PASS -H "Jenkins-Crumb:$JENKINS_CRUMB" -s \
                        -b /tmp/cookies $JENKINS_URL'/me/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' \
                        --data 'newTokenName=GlobalToken' | jq -r '.data.tokenValue')
    echo $ACCESS_TOKEN > /var/lib/jenkins/api_token.txt
fi
```

This part for you could be different, configured by your server setup:

```bash
    JENKINS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    JENKINS_USER=admin
    JENKINS_USER_PASS={{ jenkins_admin_password }}
```

ref: https://community.jenkins.io/t/can-we-create-a-user-token-through-the-api/8319/5