# Jenkins 'Add new Token' button missing in user config for a new user

Tags: jenkins

Usernames used are sample names:

In our initial setup, we have a user, 'user1'.  I have created an API token for this user.  When I create a new user, 'user2', the 'Add new Token' button is missing in the user config.  We use Matrix-based security, and the settings for these two users match.  Also, we are *not* using legacy tokens (those are turned OFF in the global config).

How do I enable the create api token functionality for this second user?

Comment: Are you trying to see "Add new token" button for user2 by logging in as user1?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `Add new Token` button is only available for the logged-in user. To generate a token for another user, you will have to actually log in as that user.

Note, for comparison, that the `generateNewToken` API endpoint also appears to only work for the current user, considering how the URL is designed. (See here: [How to get the API Token for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466090/how-to-get-the-api-token-for-jenkins))