# jenkins error: http error 403 no valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: http, jenkins, curl, http-status-code-403

I am trying to run the below command:

```
curl  -H -v "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H -d "Submit=OK" -d "mode=hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView" -d "name=prda" -d 'json={"name": "prda", "mode": "hudson.plugins.nested_view.NestedView", "Submit": "OK"}' http://wcportal-workplace.subnet1phx1.devcecphx.oraclevcn.com:8080/view/TxnPreview/createView
```

But it fails with below error:
Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

```
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
     [exec] <table>
     [exec] <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/view/TxnPreview/createView</td></tr>  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type; Name or service not knowncurl: (6) Could not resolve host: Submit=OK; Name or service not known
     [exec] <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
     [exec] <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
```

I tried most of the things mentioned in the stackoverflow link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711696/jenkins-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request"
but non seems to be working.

Comment: 403 is Forbidden. You need to send credentials

Comment: Jenkins version is : 2.284

Comment: i am very new to curl and jenkins. can u pls tell me how to send credentials in the above command?

Comment: @PrasobirMandal Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72906138/2627018

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the API Token for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466090/how-to-get-the-api-token-for-jenkins)