# Deserialize PSON file

Tags: c#, json, powershell, json.net

I have the task of de-serializing a PSON (PowerShell Object Notation) file and am struggling to get it working.
Apparently the PSON  file is a variant of JSON used by [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) which encodes the strings differently - according to [this source](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.4.latest/developer/file.pson.html)

I have tried just using the standard JSON.Net DeserializeObject method:

```
using (var r = new StreamReader(psonFilePath))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
}
```

The above code throws an exception:

> "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: @. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0."

which makes sense as a standard JSON file wouldn't have an '@' at the start.

An example of the PSON file is below:

```
@{
    shapes = @{
        'SQ4297' = @{
            shapeid = 'SQ4297'
            shapetype = 'square'
            sides = 'four'
            colour = 'purple'
        }
        'SQ6281' = @{
            shapeid = 'SQ6281'
            shapetype = 'square'
            sides = 'four'
            colour = 'orange'
        }
        'TR14' = @{
            shapeid = 'TR14'
            shapetype = 'triange'
            sides = 'three'
            colour = 'green'
        }
    }
}
```

The link mentioned above states that

> most parsers will produce usable output from PSON if they are
>   instructed to interpret the input as Latin-1 encoding

I have tried using different encodings with the JSON but get similar errors whichever way I try. I also tried removing the '@' but then run into problems because the strings are not enclosed in quotes so the parser exceptions again.

Comment: Are you sure what you've posted is valid PSON as per that link?  It says _"PSON does not differ from JSON in its representation of objects, arrays, numbers, booleans, and null values"_ and _"A PSON string... must start and end with " characters"_.  What you've posted doesn't match either of those.

Comment: Well that would explain why it doesn't work ;-)  I had missed the bit about the quotes. Maybe I need to go back to the file source and get more information about how the file is supposed to be used.

Comment: It's not just the quotes - the fact it's got `@` signs in there, no commas between any of the values, `=` instead of `:` etc etc

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yeah - point taken, I'll get more information about the file and it's origins and update the question. Thanks

Comment: The point of a valid PSON file is that it will de-serialize itself. If you run it in PowerShell as a scriptblock, it will recreate all objects that are in it.

Comment: Based on the previous comment, your file is a valid PSON file.

Comment: @JanChrbolka You are correct, it turns out the file is intended to be read by a PowerShell script. If you post your response as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: It seems the PSON format mentioned in the link I found was a red herring and it has nothing to do with Puppet. It turns out that the file is just a serialized Powershell object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there are two different meanings of PSON here.

1. PSON in relation to PowerShell, refers to PowerShell Object Notation. This is a format used to store PowerShell data objects in a file. One useful feature of a PSON file is that it can de-serialize itself when executed in PowerShell.

   For more information see this question: [Save hash table in PowerShell object notation (PSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139552/save-hash-table-in-powershell-object-notation-pson)

   The file in you question, is a valid PowerShell PSON file.
2. The other PSON seems to be [Protocol JSON](https://github.com/dcodeIO/PSON) . *"A super efficient binary serialization format for JSON"*  This, I know nothing about.

Comment: yes, this file appears to be #1  - a PowerShell object so it is never going to parse as JSON. Thanks