# How can I write a nested arbitrary associative Array value set to a .psd1 file in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, propertybag

I have a powershell Array object that is programmatically generated, something with arrays inside arrays, inside arrays, sometimes called a "property bag" or a "hashtable", but I think it's natively called an "Array containing Arrays" in the most native powershell terminology.

For example:

```
 @{
 Version  = '1.0.0'
 Name     = 'thing'
 Revision = 'c3a89cd20e19bb82f41e95e0806edc5b6cfd224e'
 Date     = '2016-12-09'
 Build    = '1234'
 Contents = @{
      "index.html" = "23dd7b993f40bb3ae8848fe104b3b767"
 }
 }
```

Generating a function to save only one specific set of contents to a .PSD1 file seems not general enough. 
I want to save that exact in-memory Array structure to a PSD1 file. Does any built-in way in Powershell exist to Persist an in-memory variable with the values above? The "opposite function" of `Import-PowershellDataFile`. I would have guessed it would be called `Export-PowershellDatafile` but no such function seems to exist.

Comment: I was just wondering about modifying a psd1 without just doing text-manipulaion...timely question!

Comment: [Powershell Pipeworks](https://github.com/StartAutomating/Pipeworks) wrote a couple a functions that might do what you are looking for: `Export-PSData` and `Write-PowerShellHashtable`

Comment: whats wrong with `Export-Clixml`?

Comment: Because I want to load it in as .PSD1.  I guess I could just round-trip in XML, but why not have round trip in PSD1 too?

Comment: Logged feature request on powershell project on github: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2875

Comment: Powershell-pipeworks functions works fine for this, they call it Property bags. Feel free to convert that comment to an answer. Total is about 185 lines of code. https://www.gitlab.com/warren.postma/hai/snippets/33366

Comment: Great question, and I suggest adding a link to your [feature suggestion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2875) to your answer. Note that these are _not_ arrays you're dealing with - only [nested] _hashtables_ (instances of `[hashtable]` (`[System.Collections.Hashtable]`)).

Comment: Did you ever solve this @WarrenP? This question is almost 2.5 years old

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `New-ModuleManifest`? Without knowing any additional details, it appears that you're creating something substantially similar to a manifest file used in a module... But even if your use case is different, you should still be able to use the cmdlet.

`New-ModuleManifest` has been around for a while (at least since v3, but I seem to recall using it with v2 as well). It allows you to define a hashtable of properties and save it down as a `.psd1`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 1):

Originated from this [Save hash table in PowerShell object notation (PSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15139552/1701026) question, I created (and still maintaining) a PowerShell cmdlet that evolved to a [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression). The ultimate goal of this script is to be able to export and import *PowerShell* objects between systems based on a *correct* PowerShell syntax rather than an exotic format like [`JSON`]( or [`XML`].
This includes differentiating between an ***array of bytes*** and a ***byte array*** but also correctly accepting (and formatting) singletons.
The output is `[ScriptBlock]` which can be easily save as an expression. The point is that (depending on the usage) it might create a security hole when eventually invoking (c.q. [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)) it (see: [Running partly trusted PowerShell code in a restricted security environment.
 `#12377`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12377)).
Anyways, I also included an `-Explore` parameter which I belief gives exactly the same output as required for the `PSD1` PowerShell Data File. I actually never thought about this usage earlier but now considering to alias this parameter and give it an exclusive meaning for `PSD1` files in my next version.
In other words:

```
$Data = @{
 Version  = '1.0.0'
 Name     = 'thing'
 Revision = 'c3a89cd20e19bb82f41e95e0806edc5b6cfd224e'
 Date     = '2016-12-09'
 Build    = '1234'
 Contents = @{
      "index.html" = "23dd7b993f40bb3ae8848fe104b3b767"
 }
 }

ConvertTo-Expression -Explore $Data # | Out-File .\MyData.psd1
```

Returns a `[ScriptBlock]` which automatically converts to the following expression when e.g. exporting it to a file or simply displaying it:

```
@{
        'Date' = '2016-12-09'
        'Revision' = 'c3a89cd20e19bb82f41e95e0806edc5b6cfd224e'
        'Version' = '1.0.0'
        'Build' = '1234'
        'Contents' = @{'index.html' = '23dd7b993f40bb3ae8848fe104b3b767'}
        'Name' = 'thing'
}
```