# ConvertFrom-Json dosent deserialize to objects

Tags: powershell

Trying to send an api request and iterate trough the response but it seems my response isnt getting  deserialize to objects .

This is the response im getting after invoke-Webrequest :

```
{"isSuccess": true, "value": null, "error": 0, "error2": ""}
```

Instead of:

```
Value error error2                                          IsSuccess
----- ---- -------                                           ---------
```

Here is the invoke im using :

```
$json = Invoke-WebRequest $RequestAPI-Method Post -Body $RequestBody -
ContentType 'application/json' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Didnt post the API/Body as they are internal. Is this an issue with PowerShell? or am I getting a wrong type response? Im kind of confused.

If more info needed let me know and i'll try to add.

Comment: No luck... Stays the same.

Comment: Can you reveal/share the actual object returned with the [`PSON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854277/1701026) cmdlet: `$Object = Invoke-WebRequest $RequestAPI-Method Post -Body $RequestBody -
ContentType 'application/json'; PSON $Object -Layers 3 -Strict`

Comment: Im sorry but im not fimiliar with PSON and couldnt find information about it.

When tried to put your command got : "the term 'PSON' is not recognized...

Comment: Sorry, I had the Parentheses on the wrong place. Retyped the comment: Try to rebuild the object: `New-Object PSObject (Invoke-WebRequest $RequestAPI-Method Post -Body $RequestBody - ContentType 'application/json' | ConvertFrom-Json)`

Comment: (I got a little confused because you call the object `$json`, instead it is an object converted *from* JSON) nevertheless, I guess that you got a JSON string returned rather then an object. So the question is: how doe the JSON file look like before you do a `ConvertTo-Json`?  In other words: what is the result from just: `Invoke-WebRequest $RequestAPI-Method Post -Body $RequestBody -ContentType 'application/json'`?

Comment: Yes i have thought about it , and saw that the Content in the json response comes back like this :
 

     "{"isSuccess": true, "value": null, "error": 0, "error2": ""}"

  Theres the " at the start and end of the content.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to *select*  the `Content` property

```
$json = Invoke-WebRequest $RequestAPI-Method Post -Body $RequestBody -ContentType 'application/json' |
Select-Object -expand Content | 
ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: Hi Martin , 

Tried it but getting the same response :

    {"isSuccess": true, "value": null, "error": 0, "error2": ""}