# Parsing PowerShell space-separated output as a table

Tags: powershell

PowerShell gives me this output back when running a command:

[image: PS Output]

```
Mod  Ports  Module-Type                         Model              Status
---  -----  -----------                         ------------------ ----------
1    48     2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advanced FC Module DS-X9448-768K9     ok
2    48     2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advanced FC Module DS-X9448-768K9     ok
3    0      Supervisor Module-3                 DS-X97-SF1-K9      ha-standby
4    0      Supervisor Module-3                 DS-X97-SF1-K9      active *
```

I'm having trouble trying to split it, because it's not tab-separated, is space-separated, therefore when i use `.split("")` the column `Module-Type` is being separated incorrectly because its content also has spaces.

I'm new at this, any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
$RS = .\Plink server@puttysession -pw "password" "command"

foreach ($RSln in $RS){
    $arr = $RSln.split('',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Write-Host $RSln "|" $arr.Length
}
```

This gives me the line and the length of the created array, the first two lines are arrays with 5 as length, the third and fourth have 9 items because of the spaces in `ModuleType`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the script with output in text format.

Comment: Please do not paste a link to a screenshot. Use proper code formatting and paste the relevant text into your question.

Comment: Based on the output, does not appear you are getting objects back, but you can use the top row to define column names, and the 2nd row to determine width of each column, and then SubString() to parse the other rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way of handling this kind of input in PowerShell is to parse it into custom objects. You can do that either with a regular expression:

```
$RS | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+([a-z]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+){2,})\s+(.*)'
} | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Mod'        = [int]$matches[1]
        'Ports'      = [int]$matches[2]
        'ModuleType' = $matches[3]
        'Model'      = $matches[4]
        'Status'     = $matches[5]
    }
}
```

or (if the columns are of fixed width) by extracting substrings at defined offsets:

```
$RS | Select-Object -Skip 2 | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Mod'        = [int]$_.Substring(0, 3).Trim()
        'Ports'      = [int]$_.Substring(5, 5).Trim()
        'ModuleType' = $_.Substring(12, 35).Trim()
        'Model'      = $_.Substring(48, 18).Trim()
        'Status'     = $_.Substring(67).Trim()
    }
}
```

The `Select-Object -Skip 2` is needed to skip over the 2 header lines.

If all columns were separated by more than one space splitting via `-split '\s\s+'` (split at 2 or more consecutive whitespace characters) would work too. However, with your data that is not the case, since at least the first 2 data rows have only a single space between the 3rd and 4th column.

Comment: That worked perfectly! thanks a lot, just one more question, how does $match split the expression? by using the Regex capturing groups?

Comment: Yes. `$matches[0]` is the full match, indexes above 0 are the capturing groups.

Answer (score 4):

Most PowerShell scriptwriters would probably say that it is bad idea to use any text tables similar to the `Format-Table` output as an input, but I like to challenge that because formatted source tables can be read by humans and if humans can read them and determine e.g. the layout with respect where a column starts and ends, a program should be able to do the same...

In some cases (e.g. for sample data at the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) site), it might even be handier than other formats like `CSV` (*which is difficult to read and only supports string data*), `XML` (*which is very verbose and therefore also difficult to read*) or `JSON` (or [`PSON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139552/save-hash-table-in-powershell-object-notation-pson), *which is better for complex data but not for a list of objects that contain simple native properties*)

Based on this thought I have written a reusable [**`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`** cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) which is available for download at the PowerShell Gallery and the source code from the [GitHub `iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) repository.

In your case the command to convert the table to an object is as simple as `$RS | ConvertFrom-SourceTable`, let me show that:

```
$RS = '
    Mod Ports Module-Type                        Model              Status
    --- ----- ---------------------------------- ------------------ -----------
    1   48    2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advance FC Module DS-X9448-768K9     ok
    2   48    2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advance FC Module DS-X9448-768K9     ok
    3   0     Supervisor Module-3                DS-X97-SF1-K9      ha-standby
    4   0     Supervisor Module-3                DS-X97-SF1-K9      active *
'

$RS | ConvertFrom-SourceTable

Status      : ok
Model       : DS-X9448-768K9
Ports       : 48
Mod         : 1
Module-Type : 2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advance FC Module

Mod         : 2
Module-Type : 2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advance FC Module
Ports       : 48
Model       : DS-X9448-768K9
Status      : ok

Mod         : 3
Module-Type : Supervisor Module-3
Ports       : 0
Model       : DS-X97-SF1-K9
Status      : ha-standby

Mod         : 4
Module-Type : Supervisor Module-3
Ports       : 0
Model       : DS-X97-SF1-K9
Status      : active *
```

And as all your data is left aligned (and every column would need a header), the columns layout can be determined from the start meaning that you might even *stream* this table input (presuming that `.\Plink` outputs each line separately) via the pipeline:

```
.\Plink server@puttysession -pw "password" "command" | ConvertFrom-SourceTable
```

<sub>(Meaning if you supply the source table as a multi-line string, the `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` cmdlet will determine column witches on the whole table, otherwise it is based on the header, past and current records)</sub>

If source tables would have a better formatting convention like "non-string data (data that need to be interpreted) is right aligned" (as actually done by `Format-Table`). You could make an assumption (as @Ansgar Wiechers did) that `Mod` and `Ports` are integers a fact. For example:

```
$Object = ConvertFrom-SourceTable '
    Mod Ports Module-Type                        Model          Status
    --- ----- -----------                        -----          ------
      1    48 2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advance FC Module DS-X9448-768K9 ok
      2    48 2/4/8/10/16 Gbps Advance FC Module DS-X9448-768K9 ok
      3     0 Supervisor Module-3                DS-X97-SF1-K9  ha-standby
      4     0 Supervisor Module-3                DS-X97-SF1-K9  ha-standby
'
```

<sub>(note that in this example `$Object | Format-Table` will give the same output as the input)</sub>

For more examples use the help: `Help ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Full`