# How to identify and index object references

Tags: powershell, object, indexing, reference

This question is related to the earlier asked question: [Is it possible to reference another property in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056194/is-it-possible-to-reference-another-property-in-a-constructor)

For my [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression), I would like to keep track of object references so that I can check whether the property object has already been serialized. For this I am creating a hash table which uses the object's `.GetHashCode()` method (of non `[ValueType]` objects) as a `Key`.
This works for quiet some objects, but not for `PSCustomObjects`.

As an example, I want identify that the `Parent` property of the `Child` property references the same `$Parent` Object:

```
$Parent = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = "Parent"
}
$Child = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = "Child"
}
$Parent | Add-Member Child $Child
$Child | Add-Member Parent $Parent
```

Meaning that I expect that `$Parent` (, `$Child.Parent`) and `$Parent.Child.Parent` referencing the same object.

But the problem is that both `$Parent.GetHashCode()` and `$Child.GetHashCode()` already return the same `Hashcode`... even they are completely different from each other.

Obviously, as suggested in the description of [How to: Test for Reference Equality (Identity) (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-test-for-reference-equality-identity), the correct way to check whether two objects have an equal reference is to use the [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
[object]::ReferenceEquals($Parent, $Child)
False
```

Not only I would like to fix this in my `ConvertTo-Expression` cmdlet, I would also like to better understand this.
Why does the `.GetHashCode()` method return the same hashcode for different PSCustomObjects?
How can I create an index list of (unique) object references?
Or, is this simply not possible and should I just index *all* non `[ValueType]` objects properties and check the whole list for `[Object.ReferenceEquals]` which the current object property iteration?

Comment: I think psobject is just not hashable - all PSObject returning same hash (not just ones you mentioned). Even an empty one. From the other side the way you are doing it now is working. Like $parent and $parent.child.parent is the same thing

Comment: Regarding hashcodes: 
Do not test for equality of hash codes to determine whether two objects are equal. (Unequal objects can have identical hash codes.) To test for equality, call the ReferenceEquals or Equals method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2