# Script out a hashtable with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Say I have a hashtable like this:

```
$headers = @{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'= "Api-Key 123456789"
}
```

When I run that, I get the hashtable placed in the $headers variable.

My question is, is there a way, using one line of code) to get it write back out like this?

```
@{'Content-Type'='application/json'; 'Authorization'= "Api-Key 123456789" }
```

The closest I can come is something like this:

```
$headers.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{"`"$($_.Name)`" = `"$($_.Value)`";"}
```

But that has the output on two lines, and adds an extra ; and does not have the surrounding @{ }

Comment: Tempting to close this as a duplicate with [Save hash table in PowerShell object notation (PSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15139552/1701026)

Comment: Makes sense, @iRon - I've marked it as a duplicate. While the linked post is about writing to a _file_, you need a _string_ representation first either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Fundamentally, converting a [hashtable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) instance to its equivalent *source-code representation* only works in *simple* cases, such as yours.

  - Converting is fundamentally limited to instance of those data types that (a) can be represented *as literals* and (b) whose values doesn't rely on being a *specific instance* of a .NET *reference type*.
- A best-effort implementation is iRon's [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertTo-Expression) function:

  ```
  # Install the script.
  # You may be prompted to add the download directory to $env:PATH
  # If not, you can find the script's full path as follows:
  #   (Join-Path (Get-InstalledScript ConvertTo-Expression).InstalledLocation ConvertTo-Expression.ps1)
  Install-Script ConvertTo-Expression

  # ->
  #  "@{Authorization = 'Api-Key 123456789'; 'Content-Type' = 'application/json'}"
  @{
    'Content-Type'='application/json'
    'Authorization'= "Api-Key 123456789"
  } | ConvertTo-Expression -Expand 0
  ```

  - `-Expand 0` requests a single-line representation; in [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron)'s own words:

> [`ConvertTo-Expression`] is able serialize more complex objects than just hashtables; you are able to define to what level you want to expand the object using the `-Expand` parameter (which I think is a more flexible parameter than the usual all-or-nothing `-Compress` switch) [...] you might even compress this further using `-Expand -1` which will also remove the unnecessary spaces.

- Ideally, PowerShell itself would provide such a command, in the form of the *inverse* of the [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile) cmdlet.

  - [GitHub issue #2875](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2875) suggests adding a complementary `Export-PowerShellDataFile` cmdlet, and the related
    [GitHub issue #11300](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11300) also discusses *in-memory* versions to complement the *file*-based ones.

---

Here's **an *approximation* of this functionality**:

```
# Sample input hashtable.
$headers = [ordered] @{
  'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
  Authorization = "Api-Key 123456789"
  AnArray = 1, 'two',3, '3" of snow'
  ABool = $true
}

# Try to convert the above back into a source-code representation.
$headers.GetEnumerator() | 
  ForEach-Object `
    -Begin { $entries = [Collections.Generic.List[string]] @() } `
    -Process {
      $name = 
        if ($_.Name -match '\W') { "'{0}'" -f ($_.Name -replace "'", "''") }
        else                     { $_.Name }
      $values = 
        $_.Value | ForEach-Object {
          if ($_ -is [string]) { "'{0}'" -f ($_ -replace "'", "''") }
          elseif ($_ -is [bool]) { '$' + "$_".ToLower() }
          else { $_ } # !! More work is needed here for increased type fidelity.     
        }
      $entries.Add("$name = $($values -join ', ')")
    } `
    -End { '@{ ' + ($entries -join '; ') +  ' }' }
```

Output:

```
@{ 'Content-Type'='application/json'; Authorization='Api-Key 123456789'; AnArray=1, 'two', 3, '6'' tall'; ABool=$true }
```

Note:

- It is easy to **adapt the above for use with `[pscustomobject]`** instances in lieu of hashtables:

  - Replace `[ordered]` with `[pscustomobject]` in order to create a sample custom object.
  - Replace `$headers.GetEnumerator()` with `$headers.psobject.Properties`, using the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views).
  - In the `-End` block, replace `'@{ '` with `'[pscustomobject] @{ '`

**Limitations**:

- Type-faithful representations:

  - Strings are single-quoted with appropriate escaping of *embedded* `'` characters.
  - Booleans are recognized and represented as `$true` or `$false`.
- Any other data type is represented *unquoted*:

  - This works with *numeric* types only...
  - ...and even there the *specific* input number type may be lost.
- Only *flat* collections of values are supported, which are invariably represented as PowerShell *array literals* of type `[object[]]` (i.e., any specific collection type other than array and any strong array typing is lost), with each element represented according to the rules above.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a type of `[PSCustomObject]` and *stringifying* it will give you those results:

```
"$([pscustomobject]$headers)"
```

returns:

```
@{Authorization=Api-Key 123456789; Content-Type=application/json}
```

Answer (score 2):

You lose quotes with Abraham's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73535438/4085331). If you really need the quotes you could use something like this

```
($headers | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -replace ',',';' -replace '^','@'

@{"Authorization":"Api-Key 123456789";"Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this way of going about it. Guess you can also just do `"@$(($headers | ConvertTo-Json -Compress).Replace(',',';'))"` as well.